Get pathname from within a Server Action in Next.js
Is there a way to get pathname from within server actions in Next.js 15?
For example, in route handlers there is request object, so we have:
export async function GET(request) {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  console.log(url.pathname);
}

But in server actions there is no request object.
As a workaround, I'm passing pathname into server action from my client component:

import { useTransition } from "react";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { signout } from "@/lib/actions";

export default function Component() {
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  const handleClick = () => {
    startTransition(async () => {
      await signout({ pathname });
    })
  }

  return <Button onClick={handleClick} disabled={isPending}>Logout</Button>
}

And then I use it to reload the page after logout:
import { deleteSession } from "@/lib/session";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export async function signout(data) {
  const { pathname } = data;
  await deleteSession();

  redirect(pathname);
}

I need this reload to re-run session checks in the middleware:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getSession, updateSession } from "./lib/session";

export async function middleware(request) {
  await updateSession();

  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/protected")) {
    // require session or redirect to login page
    const session = await getSession();
    if (!session)
      return NextResponse.redirect(
        new URL("/signin?back=" + request.nextUrl.pathname, request.url)
      );
  }

  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/signin")) {
    const session = await getSession();
    if (session)
      return NextResponse.redirect(
        new URL(request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("back") || "/", request.url)
      );
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

So, is there a way to get pathname in server action? Or maybe there is a way to reload current page from server action without knowing pathname at all?

Server actions don’t have access to the current page’s pathname or context about where they were invoked.
If you want to avoid passing the current path as a parameter to a server action, you could try handling the navigation on the client side after the server action completes.
Something like this:
'use client';
import { useTransition } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { signout } from '@/lib/actions';

export default function Component() {
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleClick = () => {
    startTransition(async () => {
      await signout();
      router.replace('/signin');
    });
  };

  return <Button onClick={handleClick} disabled={isPending}>Logout</Button>;
}

You can also try to retrieve the pathname through the referer header in the server action. Though it is not always reliable.
